# I can't change my CPU/ABI settings in the Android Virtual Device Manager

Tags: android, virtual-device-manager

I want to use the Intel CPU instead of ARM's offering for my virtual device am mysteriously stuck with the ARM machine. :(

Comment: Did you download the base images for any other version?

Answer (score 1):

Download the Intel CPU Image for the desired version on the Android SDK Manager, then create a new AVD with the Intel CPU.

Comment: how?? any links for source maybe?